# Firebase Phone Authentication in Flutter - Remove reCAPTCHA Step

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I'm working on a Flutter project using Firebase for phone authentication. However, during the authentication process, my app redirects to the browser for reCAPTCHA verification before sending the OTP to the user's phone.

I would like to remove the reCAPTCHA step and handle phone authentication directly within my Flutter app. I have followed the steps in the Firebase documentation, updated dependencies, and checked the configurations, but the reCAPTCHA step persists.

How to successfully bypass or remove the reCAPTCHA step in Firebase phone authentication for a Flutter project?

**What I've tried:**

- Updated the firebase_auth package to the latest version.
- Ensured that phone authentication is enabled in the Firebase project settings.
- Added SHA certificates.
- Enabled Play Integrity API.
- Enabled AppCheck in firebase.

I expected that by following the provided steps and configurations, the reCAPTCHA step during phone authentication would be removed, allowing the OTP to be sent directly to the user's phone within the Flutter app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.